# How to correctly implement custom controls on Angular 2

Tags: angular

By correctly, I meant in a way it behaves just like common html5 controls.
For example, in my specific case, I tried to create a custom submit-button. This custom submit button shows a loading icon when it is submitting a form. 
So for that, I've done this in the control's template:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{disabled: disabled || submitting}" [disabled]="disabled || submitting">
<span *ngIf="submitting"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></i></span>
{{displayText}}
```

And the code:

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

    selector: 'submit-button',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/submit-button/submit-button.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/shared/submit-button/submit-button.style.css']
})

export class SubmitButtonComponent {

    @Input() submitting: boolean = false;
    @Input() displayText: string = 'Submit';
    @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
}
```

And then I've done this:

```
<submit-button [submitting]="submitting" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid" [displayText]="'Submit'"></submit-button>
```

See the way I'm mapping the "disabled" attribute from the component itself to the inner control inside the template? Well, I'm not sure that's the correct approach, since I would have to do this for every single control attribute. What I'm asking here is: is there a way to seamlessly map attributes that I set when using my component to an inner control inside the component?

For instance, if instead of a button I had a text input, and I want to set it as required. It would not work, since the required would not be in the input inside the component, but on the component tag itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `@Input()` for every property and bind it to the inner control individually. There is currently no other way. The Angular2 Material team was struggling with this as well when they tried to figure out how to best create custom input elements and other form controls.